# Generate the full mesh of the room model

Tags: import, finite-element-method, regions, mesh, image3d

I want to import a 3d model to create a complete mesh of an interior model.

```
Subscript[c, air] = QuantityMagnitude[ThermodynamicData["Air", "SoundSpeed"]];
Subscript[ρ, air] = QuantityMagnitude[ThermodynamicData["Air", "Density"]];
bmesh = Import[FileNameJoin[{"C:\Users\sagalab\Documents\WolframMathematica\sample16.stl"}]];
λ = (c/Subscript[f, max]) /. {c -> Subscript[c, air], 
Subscript[f, max] -> 200};
h = λ/12;

mesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh, MaxCellMeasure -> {"Length" -> h}, "MeshOrder" -> 1]
```

```
Error;MeshRegion:Cell Polygon[{143,5865,138,137}] is degenerate
      
Error;ToBoundaryMesh:Mesh could not be generated
```

[3d model link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1342nqEoFcuaLVf2N2WgtqshdzYx_7c_C/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can not download the `sample16.stl`, maybe need to upload to another places.

Comment: It's telling you the polygon is degenerate, i.e has extremely thin triangles or two or more points on top of each other. You should process your mesh with external software like meshlab or blender to remove these offending polygons first. You could also just delete these in Mathematica, but you will likely end up with holes and artifacts in your model.

Comment: Corrected file links.

Answer (score 3):

Your input geometry has several defects:

```
mr = Import["sample16.stl"];
FindMeshDefects[mr]
```

[image]

I think you are best of in fixing these defects in the software that you used to create the STL file in the first place. As an alternative, you could generate the geometry in Mathematica; it's not too complicated.